# A book about A Little Girl and Rabbits

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

So, this book was my favorite book when I was a kid, it was around 10-13 years ago.

The story was about a little girl who ran out from her house and ran into a kind of forest and met some kind of rabbits.

Then she moved into a tree house and started to buy furniture and stuff.

Comment: Was this children's fiction? Was it illustrated? Do you remember any of the character names? When you say "some kind of rabbits" do you mean rabbits or something else?

Comment: yes, it was children's fiction and illustrated. I totally forgot the character names. And I've been remembering them as rabbits. I remember, the little girl had to have some debt by buying the furniture for her new house. She bought it from an antagonist character.

Comment: is it the book you mean ? http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/297982.Mr_Rabbit_and_the_Lovely_Present

Comment: Must... not... say... Alice.

Comment: Could it be _Watership Down_


   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down